# Very large semi-csv file- out of memory

Tags: c#, csv, out-of-memory

I have a 2.6GB semi-csv file that I need to parse.  By semi-csv I mean that it comes in the form (data,data2,data3,...),(moredata,moredata2,moredata3,...),(...).  which means new rows are formed by "),(" instead of a newline (this means essentially the entire file is one line).

My plan was to read in the file and split by "),(", then I could parse each element as needed.  Obviously, C# is having an 'out of memory' problem with it, but I can't just split the file up because I can't guarantee the split will not break up the data incorrectly.  Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Is data numeric only or can it have strings?

Comment: You need to use System.IO.BinaryReader.

Comment: Don't "read in the file". That's where it is going wrong. Stream the file and process line by line. It will be faster also.

Comment: You can't read the entire file... Thanks to encoding, it will baloon to 5gb... And you can't have a string longer of 2gb... And then there would be a `StringBuilder` to build that string. Too much memory.

Comment: Now... If there aren't string and the file is perfectly formatted (no spaces between `)` and `,` and `(` ) this problem is moderately complex (I'll say it would take me 2/3 hours)... Handling of strings is +1h, handling of strings with escapes of the quotes is +1h, handling of bad formatting is +1h... This problem could be quite hard.

Comment: @xanatos Each parenthetical "chunk" contains 11 comma-separated values that can be strings, ints or doubles.  Each "chunk" is separated by another comma and there are 0 newlines in the file, so I can't read line by line.  Whoever produced the file wasn't thinking clearly, but this is what I have to work with.

Comment: Aeon, is this for one file? if you have 2.6GB of data on one line of text then it might be better to go old school a little bit and split it over at least a few lines (scroll horizontally half way, find a point to split the text and insert a new line)

Comment: @Aeon2058 The strings are `"mystring"` or are `mystring`

Comment: Do you have a maximum possible length for the parenthesized chunks, or can you guess a reasonable largest length? If so, create a single buffer with this max size. Parse it, move what's left to the start of your buffer, and fill the buffer again to its max capacity. Repeat until the file is done.

Answer (score 0):

Totally untested, the strings must be `"mystring"`. No support for escapes in strings. No support for escape of the `"` in string. So these are not valid: `"my""quote"` nor `"my\"quote"`. The file must be perfect: no eof at the end, no new line at the end, no spaces anywhere but inside a string, no new lines anywhere but inside a string. Inside a string anything goes but the `"` (that marks the end of the string), no lines with too many elements, no lines with too few elements, no `null` handling (technically a `,,` for a string will return an empty string with no error thrown). All the types supported by `Convert.ChangeType` are supported.

Usage:

```
using (var fs = new StreamReader("myfile.txt"))
{
    foreach (var objs in ParseStream(sr, new Type[] { typeof(int), typeof(double), typeof(string) }, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        // objs is an object[] where each member is of the type asked 
        // when ParseStream was called
    }
}
```

code

```
public static IEnumerable<object[]> ParseStream(TextReader tr, Type[] types, IFormatProvider culture = null)
{
    var parts = new List<string>();
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    State state = State.WaitingForOpenBracket;

    long col = -1;
    long row = 0;

    int read;

    while ((read = tr.Read()) != -1)
    {
        col++;

        char ch = (char)read;

        if (ch == '\n')
        {
            col = 0;
            row++;
        }
        else
        {
            col++;
        }

        switch (state)
        {
            case State.WaitingForOpenBracket:
                if (ch != '(')
                {
                    throw new Exception(string.Format("Malformed begin-of-the-row at R: {0}, C: {1}, char: {2}", row, col, ch));
                }

                state = State.WaitingForData;

                break;

            case State.WaitingForData:
            case State.WaitingForColumnSeparator:
                if (ch == ',' || ch == ')')
                {
                    parts.Add(sb.ToString());

                    sb.Clear();

                    if (parts.Count > types.Length)
                    {
                        throw new Exception(string.Format("Too many parts starting at R: {0}, C: {1}", row, col));
                    }

                    if (ch == ')')
                    {
                        var parts2 = parts.Select((p, ix) => Convert.ChangeType(p, types[ix], culture ?? CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToArray();
                        parts.Clear();                                

                        yield return parts2;

                        state = State.WaitingForRowSeparator;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (state == State.WaitingForColumnSeparator)
                    {
                        throw new Exception(string.Format("Malformed column separator at R: {0}, C: {1}, char: {2}", row, col, ch));
                    }

                    if (ch == '"')
                    {
                        if (sb.Length != 0)
                        {
                            throw new Exception(string.Format("Malformed string at R: {0}, C: {1}, char: {2}", row, col, ch));
                        }

                        state = State.WaitingForEndQuotes;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sb.Append(ch);
                    }
                }

                break;

            case State.WaitingForEndQuotes:
                if (ch == '"')
                {
                    state = State.WaitingForColumnSeparator;
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.Append(ch);
                }

                break;

            case State.WaitingForRowSeparator:
                if (ch != ',')
                {
                    throw new Exception(string.Format("Malformed row separator at R: {0}, C: {1}, char: {2}", row, col, ch));
                }

                state = State.WaitingForOpenBracket;

                break;
        }
    }

    if (state != State.WaitingForRowSeparator)
    {
        throw new Exception(string.Format("Malformed end-of-file at R: {0}, C: {1}", row, col));
    }
}
```